# select div not sibling using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to expand a div when a checkbox is check but not sure best way to do it. I have multiple checkboxes on the page and want only the div below each checkbox to show. Here's what I have in the HTML:

```
<!-- Start Topics -->
<div id="topics">
    <div class="box_heading">
       <h2>Topics</h2>
       <span class="line"></span>
    </div>
    IF CHECKED SHOW BELOW DIV
    <div class="row">
       <p>
          <label for=frmTopic">Check Me #1</label> <input type="checkbox" class="TopicCheckbox" name="frmTopic" id="frmTopic01" value="1"/>
       </p>
    </div>
    SHOW THIS DIV IF CHECKED
    <div class="row" name="divComment" id="divComment01">
       <p>
        <label for="frmComment">Comment on Check Me</label>
        <textarea name="frmComment01" id="frmComment01" </textarea>
       </p>
       <div class="row" name="fileUpload" id="fileUpload">
          <input class="button green" type="file" caption="Choose files" name="file" id="file"><br/>
       </div>
   </div>
IF CHECKED SHOW BELOW DIV
        <div class="row">
           <p>
              <label for=frmTopic">Check Me #2</label> <input type="checkbox" class="TopicCheckbox" name="frmTopic" id="frmTopic02" value="1"/>
           </p>
        </div>
        SHOW THIS DIV IF CHECKED
        <div class="row" name="divComment" id="divComment02">
           <p>
            <label for="frmComment">Comment on Check Me</label>
            <textarea name="frmComment02" id="frmComment02" </textarea>
           </p>
           <div class="row" name="fileUpload" id="fileUpload">
              <input class="button green" type="file" caption="Choose files" name="file" id="file"><br/>
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Here's the jQuery which I can't get to work. Hopefully I'm close.

```
$('.TopicCheckbox').click(function() {
    if( $(this).is(':checked')) {
        //alert("clicked");

         $(this).parent().find("div[name=divComment]").slideToggle('slow', function() {
            // Animation complete.
         });
    } else {
        $(this).parent().find("div[name=divComment]").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: can you recreate this one using jsfiddle?

Comment: You can't use a `name` attribute on a `<div>` tag. However `div[name=divComment]` is not the parent of *checkbox* input but *ancestor*. use `.parents('.row')` method instead then `.next()`.

Comment: I hope you only have one #topics in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following script.

```
$('.TopicCheckbox').click(function() {
    if( $(this).is(':checked')) {
        //alert("clicked");

        $(this).parents("#topics").find("div[name=divComment]").slideToggle('slow', function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    } else {
        $(this).parents("#topics").find("div[name=divComment]").hide();
    }
});
```

You should use parents to traverse more than one level.

Thanks,

Jothi

Comment: I'm going to have multiple checkboxes and divs with unique ids but I only want to open the div if THAT checkbox is checked. Does that make sense?

Comment: In this multiple checkboxes case you can go upto the row level and then try to find the next sibling which has name as divComment. You can refer this http://jsfiddle.net/WJx4M/3/

Answer (score 1):

You need to go several levels up from the checkbox to get the div in question:

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().find("div[name=divComment]")
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PfbMr/

Answer (score 1):

`parent()` only goes up ONE level by default. Use `parents()`, or use a selector that starts higher up the tree, such as `$('#topics')`.

Answer (score 1):

ok, first of all, the divComment element has an ID, so you can always jsut refer to it using the id. You are applying this to a class so it makes me think you have multiple elements on the same page with an id of divcomment, which is invalid html, and needs to be fixed first.

the following code should work fine if that is not the case.

```
$('.TopicCheckbox').change(function() {
if( $(this).is(':checked')) {
    //alert("clicked");

     $("#divComment").slideToggle('slow', function() {
        // Animation complete.
     });
} else {
    $("#divComment").hide();
}
});
```

Comment: Yes I have a unique identifier at end of IDs so it is valid. And yes, you're right I have mulitple of these on the page and only want the one checked to open. know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/gespinha/WJx4M/1/

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#divComment').hide();

    $('.TopicCheckbox').click(function() {
       if( $(this).prop('checked', true)) {
          $('#divComment').show();
       }
    });
});
```